# SupportMapFragment and mapFragment.getMapAsync doesn't display map when called twice

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have a button that when clicked on will display map from Google Maps for Android. This works the first time I click on it, the map is loaded:

```
        mapButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //A new supportMapFragment is formed every time
                final SupportMapFragment mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
                //Adding the map to the relativeLayout placeholder
                ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(backgroundRlMaps.getId(), mapFragment).commit();
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(RecyclerViewAdapter.this); }
```

When I click the back button, the map disappears:

```
                back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mapFragment).commit();
                        back.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
```

My onMapReady method is really simple:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Map is ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Now, when I click on the mapButton for a second time, the map doesn't appear, however onMapReady is called as I can see the toast message.

Does anyone why the map is not reshown when I click again on the mapButton?

Thanks!

Comment: back.setVisibility(View.GONE) so your making the view invisible. You need to make it VISIBLE again   -- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Answer (score 0):

It's just a fragment, so try using show/hide rather than recreating a new mapfragment each time